# Counting element in python Deque

Tags: python, count, deque

I've attempted to count 1 values within my `deque` (*i.e.* `deque.count(1)`) but get the following error:

```
'deque' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I assume that I am working with a Python version that's before 2.7 when the `deque.count()` function was first introduced.

**Besides using a `for` loop**, what would be the most efficient/fastest way of counting how many 1's there are in my `deque`?

Comment: The best method could well depend on the exact version of Python you're using, so you might as well find out what it is and tell us. ;)

Comment: I was afraid of exactly that, definitely 2.4-2.6 haha - just not at work right now :/ apologies

Comment: Try: `list(the_deque).count(1)`. On my machine and python3.3 it is faster then the pure-python loop (at least for big enough lists). It's not a big improvement anyway, and with too big lists it will take more time and more memory...

Comment: Yea unfortunately the list will always be fairly large

Answer (score 1):

"without loops" requirement is strange, but if you're curious...

```
len(filter(lambda x: x == 1, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for no `for` loops, but I don't think there's any other way:

```
def count(dq, item):
    return sum(elem == item for elem in dq)
```

For example:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque([1, 2, 3, 1])
>>> count(d, 1)
2
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I assumed.  Blah, Thanks!

Comment: @Rook glad I could help. If the answer solves your problem, accept it by clicking the tick so fellow users know that your problem is solved.

Comment: @RooK here's more concise and probably slower for-loop based solution: `count = sum(x == 1 for x in q)`